# Why is my code stuck on Form2Thread.Join()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

From what I've read about this .Join(), it seems to wait for the thread in question to be done with its operations before joining and moving on with the main code. However, as far as I can tell, when my code is getting stuck on the .Join() that thread isn't running anymore and seems to have already been closed. The last line of code that is hit on the thread in question is this.Close(). Any ideas what is happening and how to fix it?

This is a C# executable program running on a Windows CE hand-held device.

I should probably also add that this is an intermittent problem that doesn't happen all the time.

This is the threads start:

```
//Start the thread to continuously receive while the LP dialog is open 
Thread Form2Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Nep450_ThreadLowPower));
```

This is the code right before the .Join():

```
else if (Form2.g_IsOKPressed)//This variable is set in the thread in qustionFomr
                        {                          
                            g_bThreadLowPowerTerminate = true;
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            Form2Thread.Join();
```

I found the source of the problem. The following line was being hit and causing an issue when the code was run a second time. Once I removed it there were no more problems.

```
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(CloseLPDialog));
```

Comment: A code example would be very helpful.  If you can show us part of your main thread (the part that's creating and starting the thread, and doing the `Join`), we might be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform does not metter. Join waits for another thread to be finished. Try writing some traces or debug messages in a thread that you are waiting for using join.

Show this.Nep450_ThreadLowPower function. There should be stack reason

Comment: Thats what I'm doing now, I tried to put a try catch in but it wouldn't let me put a catch in for some reason.

Comment: Where are you adding try-catch? What does not give you ability to do that? And what does this.Close() do? Maybe the thread is stack in that method? and what is Form2Thread class?

Comment: And I got the try catch to work, I was apparently trying to put it in the wrong spot. This.Close() is on the thread and is intended to close it once that code is done running.

Comment: You are not supposed to close the thread. Delete this line. Thread will be finished without your intrudance. If you want to terminate it explicitly (that is not recommeneded), I'd advice do Thread.GetCurrentThread().Abort(); But it's ugly and should be not used in trivial scenarious.

Comment: Not sure if it works or not with this since this form is potentially opened and closed several times. Trying to figure out how to tell if it is already open.

Comment: There is a property for the form - Visible, but I'm not sure about the name. 1. Maybe you should not close form, but only use Show() and Hide() methods? That's in case you have one form instance per your application.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good practice to check the thread's state before calling Join():

```
if (aThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
{

    aThread.Join();

}
```

EDIT: Now that you've posted a code sample, I think you should check if you really need the Thread.Sleep(500) call.

EDIT #2: Corrected the above code.

Comment: What exactly happens in your thread? Is it in a WaitSleepJoin state maybe?

Comment: It shouldn't be, the longest thread.sleep wait time is 2 seconds. And when I go to the code for the thread, I'm not able to see any values for any of the variables or hit any breakpoints which I'm assuming means that the thread is closed.

Comment: Ok, try removing the Thread.Sleep(500) call and modify your Form2Thread.Join() to Form2Thread.Join(500)